# How to write median & mode calculation function based on the group in mariadb ? So that i can use it in the query itself

Tags: mariadb

How to write median & mode calculation function based on the group in mariadb ? So that i can use it in the query itself. My mariadb version version is 5.5.
While querying when i am using partition by clause i am getting error ? Can anybody suggest me  any solution.

Comment: For future questions please regard the guide to write a good question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), for your question does not the requirements of a good question. Anyway I will try and help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently encountered the same (or rather a similar) problem. I have not solved it, yet, but I am advancing towards a solution, which I will draft here.

User defined functions (UDFs) are written in C or C++ and have to be compiled to a shared library (*.so for *nix-Systems and *.dll for Windows). They follow a certain convention, which can be found out about in the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-udf.html). I've chosen a general quantile Approach, for it can easily return the median.

```
my_bool quantile_init(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message)
{
    INIT_BUFFER();
}

//the initialization for the *current group*
void quantile_clear(UDF_INIT *initid, char *is_null, char *error)
{
    CLEAR_BUFFER();
    num_elements=0;

    ADD_TO_BUFFER(args);
    num_elements++;

    if(ISNAN(quantile_value))
        quantile_value = GET_QUANTILE_VALUE(args); //should only be called once, for its assumed to be constant
}

//add groups item
void void quantile_add(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args,
         char *is_null, char *error)
{
    ADD_TO_BUFFER(args);
    num_elements++;
}

//very simple percentile calculation, may be flawed - just for presentation
double quantile(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args,
          char *is_null, char *error)
{

    SORT_BUFFER();
    return GET_BUFFER_AT(ROUNDDOWN(quantile_value * num_elements));
}

void quantile_deinit(UDF_INIT *initid)
{
    CLEANUP();
}
```

To clarify the logic: MariaDB or MySQL first calls quantile_init in which all of your fancy initialization will take place (allocate buffers and so on). For each group that shall be aggregated the quantile_clear is called, in which you can reset the internal summary variables used and add the first value to the list. Now for each remaining row the quantile_add method is called, in which you would add the respective value. In the quantile function the quantile is calculated and returned.

After compilation as a shared library you can copy the file (libmylib.so/mylib.dll) to the plugins directory of your RDBS and load the function by calling

```
CREATE AGGREGATE FUNCTION quantile RETURNS REAL SONAME mylib
```

Now you should be able to use the function like

```
SELECT quantile(value, .5) FROM data GROUP BY category;
```

I've never undergone the whole procedure, hence all this information is of theoretical value, but according to the [MySQL Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-udf.html) it should work alike.